# Gradle build failed - SystemProp

Tags: java, gradle

trying to build java project using gradle 6.5.2 and getting an error

```
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'hello-app'. 
Could not get unknown property 'systemProp' for settings 'hello-app' of type 
org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings.
```

settings.gradle content:

```
rootProject.name = 'hello-app'
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore= '/opt/java/openjdk/lib/security/cacerts'
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword= 'changeit'
```

build.gradle content:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'io.freefair.lombok' version '5.1.0'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.2.RELEASE'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter {
        url 'https://repo.company.com/artifactory/jcenter_link/'
    }
    mavenCentral {
        url 'https://repo.company.com/artifactory/jcenter_link/'
        url 'https://repo.company.com/artifactory/jitpack'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.3.2.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.3.2.RELEASE'
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-core'
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:1.5.3'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'
    implementation 'com.company.rnd:jsonlogger:0.1.9'
    implementation 'com.company.rnd:vault-client:0.0.6'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.3.2.RELEASE'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.1'
    testImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'

    classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4+"
}

application {
    mainClassName = 'hello-app.src.main.java.com.company.rnd.apphello.ApphelloApplication'
}

test {
    systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', 'DEV'
    mainClassName = 'hello-app.src.test.java.com.company.rnd.apphello.ApphelloApplicationTest'
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"   //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'gradle-release-local'
            maven = true
        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'jcenter_link'
            maven = true
        }
    }
}
```

How could i solve it?
If i rename settings.gradle to gradle.properties i get below error:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'hello-app'.

> Could not find method classpath() for arguments [org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: move these `systemProp.*` properties to the correct place =>  `gradle.properties`file

Comment: Put build.gradle here

Comment: see https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.jfrog.artifactory  how to properly apply Artifactory plugin. you need to remove the `classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4+"`line from project's `dependencies`block